# How to find and display directory files by partial name

Tags: list, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a directory with the following files:

```
1245_cat.txt
6356_cat.txt
3564_it.txt
9867_it.txt
8437_xp.txt
6252_xp.txt
```

I am looking for a way to search and display file(s) based on partial name. For instance, if a user enters 1245, I would like to display 1245_cat.txt.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<cfset fileLocation = "\\doc_1\LOAD">
<cfdirectory directory = "#fileLocation#" 
    name = "archive" 
    type="file"
    filter="*.txt" 
    action = "list">
```

Do I then create a list: `archive_list` of all returned files and use `listContains(archive_list, "1245_cat.txt")`?

Comment: that's one option, yes.

Comment: Filtering is a better option. Though if you ever did use lists, be careful with listContains. It'll also match like 5*12345* _cat.txt or *12345*6 _cat.txt , so be sure that is the result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the filter dynamic:

Let's say the search field is named "file_name", then

```
<cfparam name="form.file_name" type="string" default="">
<cfset myFilter = form.file_name & "*.txt">
<cfdirectory directory = "#fileLocation#" name="archive" type="file" 
   filter="#myFilter#" action = "list">
```